# Options for new line path from breaker box

Tags: electrical, basement, circuit-breaker

Previous homeowner added on a kitchen to the basement without running a new line from the breaker box. Kitchen is on the opposite side of the basement as the breaker box.

Just read through this post: [How to rewire house electrical?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/46439/how-to-rewire-house-electrical) but it sounded like they weren't going to go through the attic.

Edit:

**Is it more work/cost/risk to run something up into the attic, across the house, and down to the basement than it is to cut open walls along the basement to get across the house?**

Comment: So what is the actual problem? What is needed?

Comment: apologies, edited question

Comment: Depends on how far up it is to the attic (how many floors, headers, etc) and how much attic access there is vs what's involved in running it across the ceiling of the basement. If your joists run in the direction from the panel to the kitchen, it's a reasonably simple matter of cutting a bit of drywall, fishing a cable (or 2 or 3) through an opening, then patching some drywall. Your electrician, who will have eyes/hands on the situation will be in a far better place to make that assessment than a bunch of people on the other side of the internet.

Comment: If you're not confident in one guy's estimate, get two or three electricians in to give you estimates and work plans. Go with the one that seems most reasonable to you

Comment: Is going through an attic to end up back in the basement something common/fair game? It would be going up 10ft from breaker box into attic then across and down.

Comment: Besides cost of extra cable, would come down to which was easier to access.  Imagine finished basement with nice ceiling.  Most cable paths usually go to shortest and easy access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all a matter of what's easiest/most cost effective for *your* situation. An electrician (or two or three) with hands and eyes on-site will be able to determine that far better for your house than a bunch of people making guesses from the other side of the internet (especially since we don't even have pictures to guess at).

In my house, I've run wiring down from the first floor panel, through the crawl space and up into outlets, switches and the ceiling of the first floor for various upgrades.

I've also gone down to the crawl space then all the way up an interior wall to the attic to drop into the walls and ceiling of the second floor. Sure, a trained electrician with a lot more experience than I may have chosen a different route, but I did what worked for me, and what I saved in time, effort and frustration (trust me, there was plenty of those three spent) *more* than made up for the few extra bucks in cable that I had to use.

*Your* house may be totally different.

Comment: I second this, it depends very much on your house, its age, its construction, and the preferences of the installer.  Do you have a solid concrete foundation?   Is your attic filled with 13 inches of insulation?   Do you have an older house with clear runs between the joists from basement to attic?   These are not actual questions for you, just considerations that would affect the decision and I think you need someone with experience in your area to assess it.

Comment: Thank you these are great considerations I will discuss with my local electrician. Helps me know what questions to ask.